# Answering a Broad question with a Broad answer

Tags: discussion, answers, allowed-answers

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/326241/kaathe-vs-frampt-and-endings) has been closed as too broad - basically because they're asking several questions at once. That's fine - that's not what I'm asking about. What I'm asking about is the answer.

It starts by saying

> Having asked multiple questions, I'll try to answer broadly.

I feel like this is the wrong thing to do, simply because it's acknowledging the broad question, and accepting it anyway.

The answer itself isn't *bad*, it does answer the question to a degree. My issue is mainly to do with the apparent acceptance of the broad question.

Comment: The person that answered wasn't involved in the closing decision. Perhaps they simply disagreed with how broad is 'too broad'?

Comment: Personally, I would disagree. They've been an SE member for over 6 years now, as well as identifying the "multiple questions", which the close reason clearly states: *"Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once"*.

Comment: I guess I'm just failing to see the relevance - the question got answered before it was closed, happens all the time. Closures/Reopens happen because of votes of individual members with individual interpretations of what constitutes "Too Broad" or "Unclear" etc. If you answer a question that you think is clear but others think is unclear and VTC as such, are you then in the wrong? Should we downvote or delete an answer because the question is closed? *No, I don't think so* - the answer should be judged on it's own merits irrespective of what's going on up on the question.

Comment: @Robotnik Your opinion flies in the face of how the automated system works.  Closed questions with answers get deleted all on their own.  In fact, you lose that rep gain when it gets deleted, even if all you did was have an accepted suggested edit.  That tells me there should be no incentive to answering questions unfit for the site.

Comment: @Frank - This has nothing to do with the way auto deletion or rep works. This is about users answering questions others think are too broad. Your assumption that every closed question gets deleted is incorrect - questions *can* be reduced in scope/made clear and reopened again, at which point any answer currently in existence on the question can (and should!) be evaluated by voting. (cont)

Comment: Deleting that answer while the question is closed, before the question is reopened or deleted *would* in fact *"fly in the face of how the automated system works"*. Sure, if the question gets closed and deleted, the answer is deleted too. *But that's not what's in dispute here*.

Comment: @Ben - *"I really don't believe that any fault should lie on the answers for trying to provide some help. Yes, assumptions need to be made, but that doesn't have to stop us from answering."* - a quote from [yourself](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/168614/mojang-update-on-minecraft-weve-lost-our-worlds-what-do-we-do/168646#comment227530_168646), from the [last time this was brought up](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8648/answering-an-unclear-question?rq=1) (in respect to Unclear questions)

Comment: @Robotnik that's fair :)

Answer (score 5):

[This meta question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8648/answering-an-unclear-question?noredirect=1&lq=1) kind of delves into what you are saying, if you look at Strix's answer here:

> StackExchange, and each of its child sites, is supposed to be a community for experts to provide expert answers. Questions that do not define a specific problem should not be answered, because it is impossible to provide an expert answer without a clear problem space defined.

It it not a good idea to answer a broad/closed question because of the implication that you are giving a broad/incorrect answer.

I'll give you my two sides to your two questions here.

> What I'm asking about is the answer.

The person who answered this specific question got to the heart of the question and I believe that is acceptable. His answer covered everything, went into detail about the choices and even updated it concerning comments. A well thought out answer and even an update on the answer based on what happens after you make the choice X VS Y is deserving of a +1 in my book.

> My issue is mainly to do with the apparent acceptance of the broad question.

We do not accept broad questions - you can see we close multiple broad questions per day. We also encourage (or try to) people to come back and edit their questions to get it accepted.

The question is fine now as it stands because the question has been updated to ask a single question about a single plot point in the game. Yes, this part of the game has multiple sides to it depending on whom you side with, but it is essentially asking X VS Y, what happens? Which is totally fine.